# Obtaining user's facebook access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cookies

I am working on Facebook lookin integration for my site, and would like to be able to obtain the user's access token for further interaction capabilities past just logging in.  I have gotten the login process working using the javascript SDK, and I can obtain the user's info by querying the /me edge.  From what I've read, I should be able to have my server obtain the user access token by querying the oauth/access_token edge api.

My query structure is as follows

```
HTTParty.get(URI.escape("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=1398254717088095&redirect_uri=http://portal.ggwifi.net/test_portal/&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&code=5TPMo3WelM6aDm7zbvVBkZTlV_5ydQaHPP26Ytfv7Hg.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"))
```

where code is the value stored in cookies[:fbsr_1398254717088095].

I have attempted this, but every time I try it fails with the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid verification code format.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I've read somewhere that the code needs to be broken apart at the '.', but I've tried that as well (using the part before the period and also the part after), but it didn't work either.

Do I need to manipulate the code stored in the cookie in some other way in order to obtain the token?  What am I missing here?

PS - I've also tried using the graph api explorer to obtain the token, pasting in my cookie value, but get the same error.

Comment: Of course that will not work. The way to get an access token is to show the user the login dialog. And the user can choose to use your app or not. Using values from the cookies will not work

Comment: The user has already accepted the login dialog and granted my app permissions.  But how do I make server-to-server API calls using the user's access token?  My research indicated that the fbsr cookie is a signed request, which should be able to be decoded using my app's secret key to obtain the access token, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: The fbsr cookie is something used on facebook.com and nothing you should use. You just store the access token that you got when the user accepted the login dialog and granted your apps permissions

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I found my solution in facebook's documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games/#parsingsr

The cookie is actually a signed request, but it needs to be interpreted using the following steps:

```
- Split the signed request into two parts delineated by a '.' character (eg. 238fsdfsd.oijdoifjsidf899) 
- Decode the first part - the encoded signature - from base64url 
- Decode the second part - the 'payload' - from base64url and then decode the resultant JSON object
```

My only issue now is that the cookie seems to expire very quickly, so it can't be used for very long, but I can store the token as a session variable for persistent api access.

Edit: Guess I'm not 100% there yet, because I was able to obtain the access token once (but in testing, and didn't store it anywhere) but when I try to obtain it again, facebook tells me the authorization code has already been used.  Logging out, or even deauthorizing the app and logging back in doesn't get it to create a new code either.